# Sum Values in a foreach loop in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to sum data
After getting the previous calculations on controller Laravel

```php
private $nn;

public function detailproject($code_project)
{
    $countdata = count($listdata);
    $countdata = 15 / $countdata;

    foreach ($listdata as $obj ) {
        $this->nn = $obj->percent * $countdata / 100;
        $this->nn +=($obj->persen);
    }
    
    dd($this->nn);
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an example of what type of data `$listdata` contains. Also show an example of what your expected result is. Having said that, you overwrite `$this->nn = ...` in your foreach loop. If you would put that line before the foreach it might work. Do try and provide the examples so that it's easier to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) or [`reduce()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reduce). Since it's a Laravel question, I'll go with `reduce()`

```php
$collection = collect($listdata);
$percentage = 0.15 * $collection->count();

$sum = $collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) use ($percentage) {
    return $carry + ($item->percent * $percentage);
}, 0);

dd($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning after saving data use this method where you pull data from existing columns and show them on blade file..

```
//initialize percentage if constant for every record on DB
//if not constant pull($Percentage) from DB as column as shown below.

//$x; $y are specific columns found in table in DB.

// replace mathematical signs where necessary.

// if needed as per row mask the formulae in your for each loop

$percentage = ''  

        $total = array_sum(array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; },
                $carry, $item)) * ($percentage);
```